JSON error, Unexpected character ('d' (code 100))

{"data": {"type": "VALVE_CONTROL", "id": "request-4", "attributes":
{"command": "START_SECONDS_TO_OVERRIDE", "seconds": 60}}}

Can someone help me here. Where is the error above?

Error -
{"errors":[{"id":"170a15c0-dce3-4880-8a69-41d5299926f0","status":"Bad
Request","title":"Client error","detail":"[Bad Request] Json body
application/json parsing error: Failed to decode:Unexpected character
('d' (code 100)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at
[Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]"}]}

Unfortunatley I'm not programmer and I don't understand what is the problem there. I really would appreciate some help.

nothing is wrong with json, are you using curl to make a call? this link will explain https://github.com/Lambda-3/Graphene/issues/46

This is full Curl call and it give me that error.   -w "%{http_code}" -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{"data": {"type": "VALVE_CONTROL", "id": "request-4", "attributes": {"command": "START_SECONDS_TO_OVERRIDE", "seconds": 60}}}" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxx " -H "X-Api-Key: xxx” -k "https://api.smart.gardena.dev/v1/command/1dc3f90f-5c74-446b-9ec8-c2bf07551e86:1"

you have double quotes inside and outside JSON. set external quotes as a single ones. something like this: ... -d '{"data": ..... "seconds": 60}}}' ...

Outside double quotes I can't change. They are applied automatically via Gira X1 Logic module. I can only change input > {"data": {"type": "VALVE_CONTROL", "id": "request-4", "attributes": {"command": "START_SECONDS_TO_OVERRIDE", "seconds": 60}}} <  Is it possible to change something differently here to make it work?

try to make a single quotes inside json - that is your issue, or as alternative try to make inside json double quotes with escape char like "name": ... (it might not work but try)
